# Delete user from database - GET method change to POST method

Tags: php, mysql, post, get

My question is how can i change GET method to the POST method after click action on the delete button on page Users List.

After delete using POST on top of page users.php must be message "User $name deleted!"

users.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Users</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Users List</h1>

<?php
include('db_connect.php');

$db_conn = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);


if($result=$db_conn->query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id")){
    if($result->num_rows > 0){


        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>";


        while($row=$result->fetch_object()){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row->id."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row->name."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";

    }else{
        echo "No records";
    }
}else{
    echo "error: ". $db_conn->error;
}

$db_conn->close();

?>

<br><a href="add.php">Add user</a>

</body>
</html>
```

delete.php

```
<?php

require_once 'db_connect.php';


$db_conn = @new mysqli($host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{

    $id = $_GET['id'];


    if ($stmt = $db_conn->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
    }
    $db_conn->close();


    header("Location: users.php");
}
else

{
    header("Location: users.php");
}
```

Please help! :)

Comment: why do you need to use post?

Comment: My excercise is to do this

Comment: you will have to create a form or use ajax for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `form` with hidden inputs & submit button instead of links:

Change:

```
        echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>";
```

With:

```
        echo '<td><form action="delete.php" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row->id . '"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"></form></td>';
```

& surely this should be handled in PHP:

Change:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
```

To:

```
if (isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']))
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: It works :) Thank you :)

Now after delete i must have information on the top of site user.php "User $username deleted!"

I can do this but after refresh message exists

Maybe ssesions or try cath

Comment: Glad to know it works. You can do this: If POST request deleted the element, you can redirect to delete.php with GET parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following then

> In your delete.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  //DO the deletin here
}
```

> In users.php

```
echo "<td><form action='delete.php' method = 'post'><input type = 'hidden' name = 'user_id' value = '" . $row->id . "' /><button type = 'submit'> Delete</button></form></td>";
```